# Htaccess redirects from site.com/en/category/{productId}-productname-{productEAN}.html to en/{productId}-product-name.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess

It's an ecommerce site I need to do redirects like this one:

redirects site.com/{languageIsoCode}/categoryName/{productId}-productName-{productEAN}.html to {languageIsoCode}/{productId}-productName.html

Example:
[www.site.com/en/watches/784-smart-watch-745527474.html](http://www.site.com/en/watches/784-smart-watch-745527474.html)

to
[www.site.com/en/784-smart-watch.html](http://www.site.com/en/784-smart-watch.html)

this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on


#Domain: bov.loc
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bov.loc$
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html /$3.html [L,R=301]
```

without any success, it redirects me to home page

all in the bottom my rule that I'm trying to make in this question

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html /$3.html [L,R=301]
```

bov.loc is my domain name, with http protocol because it's on my local dev but on server it will be https.

Comment: You rule requires a path containing _three_ levels (two folders and one file), your actual URL shows only _two_ : one folder and one file. Well, at leas I assume that the "www.site.com" is _not_ part of the actual path, but the http host name you requested ("domain").

Comment: true www.site.com is the host name, I also added language level

Comment: Then I suggest you revise your question. _Be precise_ in your question if you want an answer. A URL also has a protocol scheme at the beginning. And you should say _where_ you implemented that rule. And what "no success" actually means.

Comment: @arkascha, I have revised my question, I hope it's more clear now, I didn't made any rule for the protocol scheme, the protocol is https://www

Comment: The protocol scheme is either "http" or "https".

Comment: The interesting thing is the "it redirects me to home page" in your revision. That is a completely different situation. That means you have _other_ redirection rules in place. You need to add those to the question too, I am afraid.

Comment: And I assume the "product-name" versus "productname" is just a type? Like the magical removal of the EAN code now?

Comment: @arkascha product-name is just any possible product name like smart-watch , smart-phone for example, I added now my whole .htaccess , the questions is edited now all my rules are posted now, on my local it's http, but on the server it will be https

Comment: Well, take a look at that rule: `RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]` ... it will rewrite _every_ request to your "index.php" router. And it is applied _before_ your new rule comes into play.